# AMPscript - Showing a fallback value if field is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using this AMPscript to pull in a father's first name:

```
%%[ SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey) 
    SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
    SET @firstName = field(@row,"firstName") 
    SET @Father_First_Name__c = field(@row,"Father_First_Name__c") 
    IF NOT EMPTY(@Father_First_Name__c) THEN ]%% 
Dear %%=v(@Father_First_Name__c)=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

[(firstName) is used elsewhere in the email]

I need this to show simply "Hello,", if there is no value in the @Father_First_Name__c field.

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a fan of using the inline [iif()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm) AMPscript function.

```
%%[ 
SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey) 
if rowCount(@rows) > 0 then
  SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
  SET @firstName = field(@row,"firstName") 
  SET @Father_First_Name__c = field(@row,"Father_First_Name__c")
endif
]%% 

%%=iif(empty(@Father_First_Name__c),'Hello',concat("Dear ",@Father_First_Name__c))=%%,
```

The `iif` above is checking if `@Father_First_Name__c` is [empty](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm), and if it is, "Hello" is returned and output in your email. If it is not empty, the [concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) of "Dear " (with a space) and our `@Father_First_Name__c` variable is output. Note that the comma is after the `iif()` because it is applicable in both scenarios.

Also, I'd recommend adding the rowcount check as seen above to make sure your `LookupRows()` returned a row, in order to avoid an Invalid index error.

Comment: +1 `IIF` is the better answer, less code.
IF statement in email/web page become really hard to manage.

Answer (score 7):

You were literally 90% of the way there. You just need to put in an ELSE statement with the required content:

```
%%[ SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey) 
    SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
    SET @firstName = field(@row,"firstName") 
    SET @Father_First_Name__c = field(@row,"Father_First_Name__c") 

    IF NOT EMPTY(@Father_First_Name__c) THEN ]%% 
Dear %%=v(@Father_First_Name__c)=%%
%%[ELSE]%%
Hello,
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

and then it will output: `Dear John` if name present or `Hello,` if not.

Answer (score 5):

Reference: [AMPscript 201](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript201.htm)

[image]

Seems like you're nearly there, just need to add an "else" condition to handle just showing Dear if the name is blank.

```
IF NOT EMPTY(@Father_First_Name__c) THEN ]%% 

Dear %%=v(@Father_First_Name__c)=%%

%%[ELSE]%%

Dear

%%[ENDIF]%%
```